# Windows CLI equivalent to Linux lesser than symbol?

Tags: windows, linux, powershell, command-line-interface

This is my first post and I'm already apologetic as this may be too simple of a question. I'm starting to teach myself SQL and the super guide I'm following (http://sql.learncodethehardway.org) uses linux commands while I'm trying to learn on a Windows PC.

The author uses the linux command < to send inputs from a text file on the right to the program on the left. Is there an equivalent to this command in Windows PowerShell? I googled the heck out of it and searched as much as I could here but couldn't find an answer.

Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

```
cat c:\temp\q.txt | bla-bla-program
```

Comment: how to add parameter to program. like `cat pow.py | python solve MTIz`